# SQL Server recursive query·

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table in SQL Server 2008 R2 which contains product orders. For the most part, it is one entry per product

```
ID | Prod | Qty
------------
1  | A    | 1
4  | B    | 1
7  | A    | 1
8  | A    | 1
9  | A    | 1
12 | C    | 1
15 | A    | 1
16 | A    | 1
21 | B    | 1
```

I want to create a view based on the table which looks like this

```
ID | Prod | Qty
------------------
1  | A    | 1
4  | B    | 1
9  | A    | 3
12 | C    | 1
16 | A    | 2
21 | B    | 1
```

I've written a query using a table expression, but I am stumped on how to make it work. The sql below does not actually work, but is a sample of what I am trying to do. I've written this query multiple different ways, but cannot figure out how to get the right results. I am using row_number to generate a sequential id. From that, I can order and compare consecutive rows to see if the next row has the same product as the previous row since ReleaseId is sequential, but not necessarily contiguous.

```
;with myData AS
(
  SELECT
    row_number() over (order by a.ReleaseId) as 'Item',
    a.ReleaseId,
    a.ProductId,
    a.Qty
  FROM OrdersReleased a

  UNION ALL

  SELECT
    row_number() over (order by b.ReleaseId) as 'Item',
    b.ReleaseId,
    b.ProductId,
    b.Qty
  FROM  OrdersReleased b
  INNER JOIN myData c ON b.Item = c.Item + 1 and b.ProductId = c.ProductId                           
)
SELECT * from myData
```

Comment: as an alternative, I have tried writting it like this    ;with myData AS
(
  SELECT
    Row_number() over (order by ord.ReleaseId) as 'Item',
    ord.ReleaseId,
   ord.ProductId,
    ord.Qty
  FROM  
   OrdersReleased ord
)

  SELECT
    max(c.ReleaseId) as 'Release',
   c.ProductId,
    sum(c.Qty) as 'Qty'
  FROM  
   myData c
  LEFT JOIN myData d ON d.Item = c.Item + 1 and d.productid = c.productid
  group by c.item, c.releaseid, c.productid, c.qty
  order by c.ReleaseId

Answer (score 0):

Usually you drop the ID out of something like this, since it is a summary.

```
  SELECT a.ProductId,
    SUM(a.Qty) AS Qty
  FROM OrdersReleased a
  GROUP BY a.ProductId
  ORDER BY a.ProductId
```

-- if you want to do sub query you can do it as a column (if you don't have a very large dataset).

```
SELECT a.ProductId,
       SUM(a.Qty) AS Qty,
       (SELECT COUNT(1)
           FROM OrdersReleased b
           WHERE b.ReleasedID - 1 = a.ReleasedID
           AND b.ProductId = b.ProductId) as NumberBackToBack
  FROM OrdersReleased a
  GROUP BY a.ProductId
  ORDER BY a.ProductId
```

Comment: I am not sure I follow. Row_number() plus the ProductId establish the relationship between the records. I agree it can be dropped from the final SELECT, but not sure how to make the query work without it.

Comment: Try changing my SQL to fit your names.  Doesn't the 3rd column remove the need for row_number()?

Comment: It would except that the ReleaseId is not necessarily consecutive, so b.Id - 1 = a.ID won't always hold true, that is why I had to add the row_number().

Comment: I'm not clear on what you want. Wouldn't everything with a count of 2 or more be counted as being "consecutive" ?

Comment: It is close, but it suffers the same problem that I have been stuck against. SELECT COUNT(1) will flag the record if it is consecutive, but it won't totalize the qty. Your query is missing the GROUP BY clause too. I wish the comment section supported the formatting of the question section - SELECT a.ProductId,
  SUM(a.Qty) AS Qty,
  (SELECT COUNT(1)
    FROM OrdersReleased b
    WHERE a.ReleaseID - 1 = b.ReleaseID
    AND b.ProductId = a.ProductId) as NumberBackToBack
FROM OrdersReleased a
GROUP BY a.ReleaseId, a.ProductId